# Need to Clean the .csv file

Tags: excel, vba

I Have tried to  clean the .csv file  to remove all the unneccessary characters.It removes all except "?" .Tried through vb script. I have downloded .csv file and need to parse it and upload to a site. But the content shows the charactes like

This is from .html file i created

�
?We believe that

Below one the actual content in file not same as above(in content)
[image]

[image]

survey have noted, it isn't clear?

?Our goal is All the "?" are not required except in questions.the are occuring at every now and then.

Comment: The recent code is missing.
Furthermore: please edit your post to inline the images if they're part of your question and edit the question title to be a question.

Comment: You can try saving the .csv file in UTF-8 Encoding from Notepad, or specify the encoding in the .html file http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp

Answer (score 1):

To remove "?" in Excel, you can use `~?` in the Find and Replace dialog and leave the Replace with: blank.

[image]

For the � characters, you can try copy pasting them in the Find what: field.